# python matplotlib making heat map out of tuples (x,y,value)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tuples of 3 numbers that I want to plot in a heat map.  The first 2 numbers are variables/coordinates and the third is the value.  I think the easiest way might be to turn them into a 40X40 data frame and use `plt.pcolor(df)` but I can't figure out how to turn it into a data frame.  Any other way to do it would be appreciated too.  I'm generating the tuples with this code `tuples.append((var1,var2,value))` in a for loop so I could put them directly into a data frame or anything else(don't know how though).  Thanks to anyone who can help me!

`[(-0.2, -0.2, 2.46), (-0.2, -0.19, 2.58), (-0.2, -0.18, 2.53), (-0.2, -0.17, 2.48)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating tuples, I would recommend creating three different lists of the same length. Then you can use **numpy.histogram2d**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# here are the three lists
# for example, you could do random values to demo
x = np.random.randn(8873)
y = np.random.randn(8873)
weights = np.random.rand(8873)

heatmap, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, weights=weights)

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the image continuous? Histogram plot has discrete intervals